# centering a CGRect in a view

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uiimage

I have an image displaying in a CGRect. how do I center the rect in the view?

here's my code:

```
UIImage * image = [UIImage imageNamed:place.image];
CGRect rect = CGRectMake(10.0f, 90.0f, image.size.width, image.size.height);

UIImageView * imageView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:rect];
[imageView setImage:image];
```

I've tried **imageView.center** but to no effect.

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

UIView's `center` is a property, not a method.

You need to calculate the actual location you want to put it in. You can do this by setting the frame of the view, or by setting its center, which is simpler in your case.

You don't say what view you then go make `imageView` a subview of. If you're putting it inside something called `superview`, you could do this:

```
CGPoint superCenter = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX([superview bounds]), CGRectGetMidY([superview bounds]));
[imageView setCenter:superCenter];
```

Answer (score 55):

Looking at:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/coregraphics/cggeometry

You can do:

```
CGPoint center = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(mainRect), CGRectGetMidY(mainRect));
```

Answer (score 7):

Position the imageView in the parentView based on the size and origin of the parentView's rect.

Given a parent view named parentView:

```
float parentRect = parentView.frame;
float imageRect = imageView.frame;

imageRect.origin.x = (int)(parentView.origin.x + (parentRect.size.width - imageRect.size.width) / 2);
imageRect.origin.y = (int)(parentView.origin.y + (parentRect.size.height- imageRect.size.height) / 2);
imageView.frame = imageRect;
```

Casting the origins to int ensures that your centered image is not blurry (though it may be off center by a subpixel amount).

Comment: suggest use floor(parentView.origin.x + ...) instead of (int)(parentView.origin.x + ...), because origin.x is CGFloat. If you cast into int, then it will be cast back to float again.

Answer (score 6):

```
CGRect r = thingToCenter.frame;
r.origin = parentView.bounds.origin;
r.origin.x = parentView.bounds.size.width / 2  - r.size.width / 2;
r.origin.y = parentView.bounds.size.height / 2  - r.size.height / 2 + 12;
thingToCenter.frame = r;
```

Answer (score 5):

```
CGRect CGRectIntegralCenteredInRect(CGRect innerRect, CGRect outerRect) {
    CGFloat originX = outerRect.origin.x + ((outerRect.size.width - innerRect.size.width) * 0.5f);
    CGFloat originY = outerRect.origin.y + ((outerRect.size.height - innerRect.size.height) * 0.5f);
    return CGRectIntegral(CGRectMake(originX, originY, innerRect.size.width, innerRect.size.height));
}
```

Comment: you should make use of `CGRectIntegral()` instead of doing `floorf()` by yourself.

Answer (score 1):

For Swift 4:

```
CGPoint center = CGPoint(x: buttonRect.midX, y: buttonRect.midY)
```

Answer (score 0):

If the function is called frequently, you can also use macros as shown here for simplicity.

```
#define Center(x) CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(x), CGRectGetMidY(x));
```

Then use it like

```
CGPoint myPoint = Center(myRect);
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 4

```
let center = CGPoint(x: bounds.midX, y: bounds.midY)
```